# Exporting plot as .eps in cloud version

Tags: export, wolfram-cloud, eps-format

I am a total beginner with Mathematica and in the desktop version, I can just select my plot and export it as a .eps. I can not find out how to do it in the cloud version, just right click and save it as a .png.
`ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[CircularGrowth,seed,{{{200}}}]]`
For example this one I just execute shift+enter and export in the desktop but I have no clue how to do it in the cloud version.

Comment: Hm. In the locally installed version, one could use the command `Export`, but I do not know how this is handled in the cloud version, because one has to supply a path to which _Mathematica_ as write access... (I have no experience with the cloud version, so hopefully somebody else can help.)

Comment: To be more specific, the following is an working example: `Export[CloudObject@"plot.eps",ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[30, {{1}, 0}, 50]],"EPS" ]` Then the plot.eps file will be found in Home directory of Wolfram cloud.